# User controls inheriting form another user control in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, user-controls

I made a User control in C# in VS2012 in design mode.

I want to make other user controls that partially show the same information.
So I want to reuse part of the screen, but add other textArea's and textlabels to it.

I want the `NewUserControl` to inherit not only the methods and properties of this user control but also the group box, that contains the information that must be shown on every other user control.

I have written the constructor like this (see below), but I can not find out how to get the `Groupbox` of the `BasisUserControl` into the designArea of NewUserControl.

```
public partial class NewUserControl : BasisUserControl {

    public NewUserControl() {

        InitializeComponent();
        BasisUserControl arrangement = new BasisUserControl();

        this.Add(arrangement)  <=== would like to do some thing like this
        ...
    }
```

Is there a way to inherit the controls in the designer?

Comment: Just inheriting is fine. It will give you then groupbox etc. remove these two lines `BasisUserControl arrangement = new BasisUserControl(); this.Add(arrangement)`

Comment: Encapsulation as an alternative to inheritance is fine, doing it both ways doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thx Sriram, it works indeed.  Couldn't be easier.

Comment: Hans, I was confused because I didn't see anything in the design view.   And it's the first time I use the User controls.

Comment: the initial constructor was missing